# obtain rss response

Tags: c#, http, rss

how would I be able to do something like http://myanimelist.net/modules.php?go=api#verifycred

aka "curl -u user:password http://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml"

I wish to option the id
my code so far is

```
string url = "http://myanimelist.net/api/account/verify_credentials.xml";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType = "xml";
request.Method = "GET";
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("xml/user/id"); // i think this line?
Stream reqstr = request.GetRequestStream();
reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);                 
reqstr.Close();
```

but I get a error on         "`reqstr.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)`"
Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type, I have tried googling but with no prevail, I am using c#

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet is trying to send a `GET` request with request data (you're calling `GetRequestStream` and then writing some data to the request stream). The HTTP protocol does not allow this - you can only send data with `POST` request.

However, the API that you are trying to call is actually doing something different - you do not need to send it the XML data. The XML data (with user ID and user name) is the *response* that you get when you successfully login.

So, instead of calling `GetRequestStream` and *writing* the XML data, you need to call `GetResponse` and then `GetResponseStream` to *read* the XML data!